# Oracle Error ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Am I doing anything wrong while Update query in .Net. I am getting the error and this is the only way I know. Is there any other way to update byte array document to oracle database. The conditions are all good I checked while debugging.

```vb
Dim data As Byte() = lDS.Rows(0)(pFieldName)             
Dim strData As String
Using fs As New FileStream(pFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim br As New StreamReader(fs)
    strData = br.ReadToEnd()
    br.Close()
End Using

Dim oradb As String
oradb = String.Format("Data Source={0};User Id={1};Password={2};", lOracleDB, lUserID, lPassword)
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)

conn.Open()

Dim strCondition As String = pSQL.ToLower()
strCondition = strCondition.Substring(pSQL.IndexOf("where"), pSQL.Length - pSQL.IndexOf("where") - 1)
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + pFieldName + " = :" + pFieldName + " " + strCondition

Dim parmData As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter
parmData.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

parmData.OracleType = OracleType.Clob
parmData.Size = strData.Length

parmData.ParameterName = pFieldName
parmData.Value = strData
Dim cm As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand
cm.Connection = conn
cm.Parameters.Add(parmData)
cm.CommandText = sql
'At below line I am getting the error
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: You mention a "byte array" in your question but then everything in your code indicates text.  Is the database column supposed to be storing text or binary data?

Comment: you can see in first line of code Dim data As Byte() = lDS.Rows(0)(pFieldName)   it is byte array then I converted it into a string not sure if this is the correct way to store. The column is having BLOB datatype and every value is visible as BLOB.

Comment: Um, yes I can see that `data` variable declared and set but you don't use it again anywhere in the code.  You say that you convert it to a `String` but you don't.  You open a file and read text from that file and then save that.  Your `Byte` array is ignored.

Comment: Also, you say that your column is type `BLOB`, which is "**BINARY** large object" but then you don't use binary data and you even set the type of the parameter to `OracleType.Clob`, which is "**CHRATER** large object".  If you want to save binary data then you need to actually get binary data to save and you have to specify that it is binary data when you save it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is horribly verbose.  Verbose code is not wrong bit it tends to be harder to read and thus more error-prone.  If you want to save binary data from a file to a database then you can do it fairly simply like so:

```vb
Dim data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)

Using connection As New OracleConnection(connectionString),
      command As New OracleCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = :MyColumn", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("MyColumn", OracleType.Blob, -1).Value = data

    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

I don't use Oracle so I'm not sure whether it works exactly the same way as SQL Server in this regard but the third parameter to `Add` is the size of column and -1 is used for `MAX`.  That may or may not be applicable to a `BLOB` column so omit that argument if it doesn't and set it to the appropriate value if it does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I am getting Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 30 error at last line of above code.